# Is it necessary for a statement to have an inverse in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, inverse, propositional-calculus

I know that it may be rather self-evident that every statement must possess an inverse, however, is there a way to prove this in propositional calculus or is it considered an axiom?

(Note: By the inverse of a statement I mean its negation)

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse"? Is the inverse of a proposition its negation?

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, indeed.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosen: In that case you can produce a negation of any statement by enclosing it in $\neg(\cdots)$. Since you already know that, what _other_ kind of answer do you expect to this question?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know how to produce a negation, as you stated, but I am wondering if it is taken as an axiom which must be true for every statement, or if it has some reason behind as to why it is true. In other words,miss there a statement which does not have an inverse?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus , item 2 under "The _language_ of $\mathcal{L}$", which is how the wff you are asking about is formed.

Comment: "Inverse" is the wrong word. The [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)) of a conditional statement $P\to Q$ is the statement $\neg P \to \neg Q$ (the converse of the contrapositive).

Comment: Not in the implicational propositional calculus or the equivalential propositional calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can form a negation of every formula is simply a property of the logical language. It will be formally stated as part of the definition of "well-formed formula": Whenever $\varphi$ is a formula, $¬(\varphi)$ is a formula too. You could consider that an "axiom" (the distinction between axioms and definitions being somewhat fluid) if you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's a related question, which I suspect might be part of what the OP intends to ask:

> Is "logic without negation" a thing?

The answer is yes, in a variety of ways:

- In **intuitionistic logics**, we do have the symbol "$\neg$"; however, it does not behave the way we might expect negation to behave. For example, "$\varphi \vee \neg\varphi$" is usually not provable. Now, an intuitionistic logician may well argue that really, it's *classical* logic which has a weird notion of negation; however, I'm assuming the OP is coming from the perspective of classical logic, in which case I think intuitionistic logic is at least partially a "logic without negation" (but, don't push that too far!). A related class of examples is **paraconsistent logics**.
- Another example, without anything that even *looks* like negation, is **dependence logic** or its variants. Dependence logic is the logic of, well, dependence: it's the natural logical system you would use to express statements like "for each $x$ and $y$, there is a $z$ depending only on $x$ and a $w$ depending only on $y$ such that . . .". Such statements are in general not expressible in first-order logic; they correspond the $\Sigma^1_1$ assertions, which are not closed under negation. Perhaps surprisingly, if there are sentences $\varphi,\psi$ of dependence logic such that every structure satisfies exactly one of $\varphi$ and $\psi$, then $\varphi$ (and $\psi$) is actually a first-order sentence! So first-order logic captures the "negation-friendly" part of dependence logic.

There are other examples you may or may not find relevant - some many-valued logics might count, depending on what exactly you're asking for - but these are a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

More formal proofs exist, but basically:

Every atomic predicate always has a negation.   If $p$ is such a predicate, $\neg p$ is the negation.

Every logical connective will have a dual; thus every compound predicate has a negation through deMorgan style rules of dual negation.   If $\circ, \bullet$ are such duals, and $p, q$ are predicates, then $\;\neg(p \circ q) = \neg p \bullet \neg q\;$.

[Note: $\neg (p\to q) \;=\; \neg\neg p \wedge \neg q$]

Every quantifier will have a dual; thus every quantified statement has a negation.   If $\mathcal {Q, \bar Q}$ are dual quantifiers, and $p$ a predicate, then $\;\neg (\mathcal Q p) = \mathcal {\bar Q} (\neg p)\;$.

Thus every well formed statement will have a negation, which is a well formed statement.

Comment: You can of course _define_ a two-place truth function that is De Morgan dual to $\to$, but I'm not aware that it has any halfway standard notation (or, for that matter, natural axioms or rules pertaining to it in proof systems).

Answer (score 1):

In general science, there's a distinction between definitions and axioms that I think is important to recognize.

- A **definition** arbitrarily associates a linguistic symbol with an algorithm. Examples include "Let X = 5", "Let Red be 400-484 THz," "Let +(x,y) be the addition algorithm," &c.
- An **axiom** is a type of proposition *utilizing* definitions that is accepted as self-evident. An example is the commutative property of addition in $\mathbb{Z}$: "+(x,y) = +(y,x)".

Axioms are propositions that need not be proved; definitions are **not** propositions *and thus cannot be proved or disproved*.

I could point to a red house and say "I declare this color is called Moob." It's nonsensical and backwards to ask, "Can you PROVE that it's Moob?" The only "proof" to be given is the tautology that it meets the requirements of the definition I just gave.

Logical negation of a statement, in its rawest form, is arbitrarily *defined* as the statement that has opposite truth values to the original statement. The existence of a negation is implied by the presence of the elements of its definition, namely, the existence of a statement that HAS truth values upon which the definition can be applied.

As others have already suggested, if the logical inverse is defined in your branch of logic then there is no proof to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: given a quantified wff F, there is an algorithm to negate F: you start with the outermost quantifier, negate it, and do so until you are done with the quantifiers. Negation at each point preserves well-formedness. Negations are done like this:

1)~$(\forall x P_{xyz..})$ is $\exists x $ ~P

2)~$(\exists x P_{xyz..})$ is $\forall x$ ~$P_{xyz..}$

And this allows you to construct a negation.

EDIT: You can see propositional logic as having 0-predicates and being unquantified. It ultimately comes down to DeMorgan's rules:

$1)$ ~($A$ or $B$)=~A or ~B .
$2)$ ~(A and B)= ~ A or ~B . This gives you all you need. Expanding: We have that $ A \implies B$ is equivalent to ~$A$ or $B$.

We then have a finite collection of connctives like And, Or, and $\implies$ from which we can construct all formulas ( we also have the Prenex form , which I can expand on if you would like me to ), together with a finite collection of atomic formulas $A,B,C$. We then apply DeMorgan's rules to the formulas.

We then do something similar to the above case.

Comment: The question is about the _propositional_ calculus; there are no quantifiers. (And even when there are quantifiers around, simply sticking $\neg$ in front of the whole shebang already produces a perfectly good negation).

Comment: OK, but I guess what matters the most in the end is that the OP found it satisfactory, and I gave some additional detail, Besides, Predicate logic is "embedded" in Predicate logic.

Comment: I just noticed the quantifies (I haven't formally studied predicate logic, yet I do know it has quantifiers as opposed to propositional calculus)

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú: Sure, sorry, I am editing in order to address that.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú: I rewrote; please see the edit and let me know if that answers your questions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I rewrote to cover the case of Sentence Logic.

Comment: @Gary: It is still a complete mystery to me where you're going with all that complexity. In order to form the negation of $\varphi$, you put first a negation sign, then an opening bracket, then the symbols of $\varphi$, and then a closing bracket. That's all there is to it. Your flurry of complexity does nothing but produce a _different_ wff that happens to be logically eqiuvalent to the negation of $\varphi$, but there's nothing in the question or the answer to indicate what you think you achieve by that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Well, I think there is something to be said for _how_ this is done in practice, and not just a purely formal argument.

Comment: @Gary: How this is done **in practice** is to write down the formula you want to negate, and then write "$\neg($" to the left of it and "$)$" to the right. Your rewriting that seems to aim to push the negation signs down to the atom level has nothing to do with the simple task of writing down the negation of the original formula, and serves no purpose at all in the context of this question.

Comment: I have to agree with Henning here, it seems that the complexity is kind of an overkill here.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú: Part of the way I see MSE is that it may help someone down the line , who reads this .

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I guess we live in different environments; that is not how is done where I study/work.